# <PHP> The images doesn't appear when I use include

Tags: php, image, path, include, show

I want to make the images to appear from another directory, instead of copying the whole images folder.

The images folder bath is correct 
http://store2.up-00.com/2015-07/1436323416451.png

```
  <img src="../../images/news_images/yaradress1.jpg"/>
<td> <img src="../../images/news_images/<?php echo $image;?>"/></td>
```

Whenever I use include I get an empty images

http://store1.up-00.com/2015-07/1436323551751.png

The bath of  required images folder :D:\xampp\htdocs\site1\images\news_images

the php file I want the images to appear in :D:\xampp\htdocs\site1\admin\includes\view_post.php

How to fix it ??

Comment: What is your document root? Based on it, you can set the image src correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,  I inserted the images folder root, and the required php file that has the scr code inside.            The main folder of the project called "site1"

Comment: In that case, doesn't it work if you use just: src="/images/news_images/<?php echo $image; ?>" ?

Comment: D:\xampp\htdocs\site1\admin\includes\view_post.php right??? Whats the image entire location???

Comment: "Mindastic"   No it doesn't because the php file in another directory.

Comment: "hemnath" the image location  : D:\xampp\htdocs\site1\images\news_images/yaradress1.jpg